# CMAKE removes ".lib" extension when using target_link_libraries

Tags: c, cmake, armclang

In my project I have something like this:

```
target_link_directories(my_target PRIVATE
  /path/to/lib
)

target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE some_library.lib)
```

but when I build, the generated link line becomes `-lsome_library` and linker can not find it because of that. If I put another `.lib` to it, like this

`target_link_libraries(my_target PRIVATE some_library.lib.lib)`

then generated link line becomes `-lsome_library.lib` and linker successfully finds it. I'm on Ubuntu, and compiler/linker I'm using TI's `tiarmclang/tiarmlnk`.

Is there a way to tell Cmake not to remove `.lib` suffix. Note that for other suffixes, like `.aer5f` everything works fine.

Comment: Have you considered not naming your library with a `.lib` extension in the first place?  Such a naming scheme is highly unconventional in the Unix world.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not naming it, it is a library that comes from a project that I'm not in control of.

Comment: What is the full file name of that library?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Full name of the library is `some_library.lib`. Full path would  be `/path/to/lib/some_library.lib`. I tried using `find_library`, and it finds it successfully when I set CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIX to empty string, but I can not use `find_library` since there are some libs that needs to be built before my target (with `add_dependancy`), and than `find_library` fails for them, because they are still not built. So, I am wondering if there is something similar to CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIX that I can use to solve my problem in the question.

Comment: Neither -lsome_library nor -lsome_library.lib should find that file on Linux. -lsome_library will find either libsome_library.so or libsome_library.a. Llikewise, -lsome_library.lib will find libsome_library.lib.so or libsome_library.lib.a.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I don't why, but if I put `some_library.lib.lib` in the `target_link_libraries`, it finds it. I get `-lsome_library.lib` on the console in that case. Also, as I said, other specific extensions works fine. It's a shame that Cmake doesn't have an option to override somehow default behavior (automatically adding/removing suffixes and prefixes). As I said, for `find_library` there are flags that do something like that, like CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIX/PREFIX

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that you are not using the standard linker. Everything is possible then I guess. CMake won't know how to generate correct flags for it. 
 Try using the full path to the library instead, or play with IMPORT_PREFUX and IMPORT_SUFFIX properties.

Comment: It turned out that `CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` was set to `.lib` somewhere in the project. When I have set it to an empty string, the `.lib` suffix was propagated to generated link line. Still not sure why `target_link_libraries" is removing this suffix when generating link lines...